# i am stuck in adding images in laravel 8.0

Tags: laravel

The `hinhanh` must be an `image`.

The `hinhanh` must be a file of type: `ipg, png, jpeg, gif, svg`.

The `hinhanh` has invalid `image dimensions`.

```
'hinhanh'=>'required|image|mimes:ipg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048|dimensions:min_width=100,min_height=100,max_width=1000,max_height=1000',
```

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: error: The hinhanh must be an image.
The hinhanh must be a file of type: ipg, png, jpeg, gif, svg.
The hinhanh has invalid image dimensions.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post your form element

Comment: Check then either you are not passing "hinhanh" in your form,  be sure that the name attribute is hinhanh in your form. Otherwise the validation rules are correct if this file doesn't meet the requirements

Comment: Please add some more code and dd($request->all), how are you sending the image, are you using enctype='multipart/form-data' in your form?

Comment: do i use enctype = 'Multiart / form-data'

Comment: @CuongPhamManh edit your question, otherwise it is impossible to help you

Comment: Try with `mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Make sure your `<form>` element has `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute.
2. Make sure you get the image in the request, it must be a file (not string) (you can test it by `dd($request->hinhanh)`).

If it's not the case, please provide more code or full error message.

Comment: <form action="{{route('phimle.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/from-data">

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Hình Ảnh Phim lẻ </label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="hinhanh" >
                        </div>

Comment: Show us your $request->dd();

Comment: $phimle = new Phimle();  
        $get_image = $request->hinhanh;
        $path = 'public/uploads/Phimle/';
        $get_name_image = $get_image->getClientOriginalName();
        $name_image = current(explode('.',$get_name_image));
        $new_image = $name_image.rand(0,99).'.'.$get_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $get_image->move($path,$new_image);
        $phimle->hinhanh = $new_image;
        $phimle->save();